# vim netrc password re-entering

Tags: vim, .netrc

I connect to a ftp server with vim and netrc. I don't have the password stored in .netrc because of security.

So when I connect to my server I have to enter the password, which is cooland it works. But if I change the directory, open a file etc. I have to re-enter my password after every action.

Is there a way to have it remember it after entering it once?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you *don’t* use `.netrc`, that will work. It will prompt you for your login name as well as the password, though.

If you want to keep your `.netrc` for other purposes and just not use it in Vim, use

```
:let g:netrw_ignorenetrc = 1
```

---

A better solution, of course, would be to switch to some SSH-based access method. Then you can make use of the SSH agent to evade the whole issue entirely.